# Is vector::shrink_to_fit allowed to reallocate?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

This member function, that has no defined effect in the standard (only remarks), would have limited use if not allowed to reallocate. But the only paragraph I found in the standard that seems to apply would be 23.2.1/11:

> "Unless otherwise specified (either explicitly or by defining a function in terms of other functions), invoking a container member function or passing a container as an argument to a library function shall not invalidate iterators to, or change the values of, objects within that container."

Since reallocations invalidate iterators, would this imply that shrink_to_fit cannot formally reallocate? If so, the function could only have effect on implementations where reducing capacity does not reallocate, if any...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree, the intention is obviously that `shrink_to_fit()` can reallocate, so it should be allowed to invalidate iterators.

It would be possible to only honour the request if the implementation provides a `realloc()`-like feature for allocators that guaranteed not to move the memory when shrinking the block, which would not invalidate iterators. But I don't believe that's what's intended, as implied by the [recently-added requirement](http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2033) that `T` is `MoveInsertable` into the vector, because that requirement is only relevant if the elements are moved to new locations, which would invalidate iterators.

I think you should [submit an issue](http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue) to get it clarified that `shrink_to_fit()` can invalidate iterators. The issue would apply to `basic_string`, `deque` and `vector`.

Comment: where is the requirement for T to be MoveInsertable?

Comment: 23.3.6.3 [vector.capacity] paragraph 7 in the current working paper, it was added post-C++11 by [LWG 2033](http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2033). N.B. the term is "`MoveInsertable` into _X_", it doesn't make sense to say a type is just `MoveInsertable` you have to say what you're inserting it _into_

Comment: Sure those additions clarify a lot the intended effect of the function.