# Will this method involve memory reallocation and thus influence its efficiency?

Tags: c++, file, vector, ifstream

I got to find that we could read the contents of a file into a std::vector like this:

```
  ifstream fin(..., ios::in);
    std::vector<char> buf(
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin), 
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Will this method cause plenty of memory reallocation like when I call `buf.push_back();` for many times? What is the fastest or best method to read a file into a `std::vector`?

Edit:
By the way, I find there is a method to read a file into a stringstream:

```
stringstream ss;
ifstream fin(..., ios::in);
fin >> ss.rdbuf();
```

Will this method have same problem of memory reallocating ?

Comment: The time spent for reallocation will be nothing compared to the time for IO.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::istreambuf_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) is an input iterator, so the distance between begin and end is not known in advance. There will be several reallocations during the constructor, unless the file is very small. For a random access iterator the distance would be known and in such case the constructor could avoid the extra memory allocations.

If you roughly know the size of the file, you can use [`reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) before reading:

```
std::vector<char> buf;
buf.reserve(file_size);
buf.insert(buf.end(), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin), 
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Comment: Reading the size of the file, reserving that much space and then restarting reading into vector will make it inefficient. The time for the reallocation is negligible when compared to the time spent in IO. Especially when the input file is large since `seekg` has to go over the complete file to get the size.

Comment: @theWiseBro reallocation  of N bytes instead of M bytes involves allocating N bytes, copying all information, then  de-allocating old storage.With large numbers THAT is inefficent. If reserving is a problem, then a reallocation-free storage might be used, eg. a list of predefined chunks.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie let's simplify. Let's say time for n bytes, memcpy takes N units. Total time when realoocating = `N+N/2+N/4...` = `2*N`. Let's say the OP has an nvme ssd. Even then transfer from memory is over 10x ~ `10N`. Reading two times = `20*N`. That's 10 times the difference in the best case(assuming my calculations were correct).

Comment: @theWiseBro that's why you don't need to read file to know its size in any modern file system, haha. That and you'd better to desing file format to have exact sizes of data stored and offsets in header.

Answer (score 0):

Vector keeps the data allocated sequentially.
When a new element is added it may have no memory free after the last element, then it need to move all the data to a place in memory where it has enough room to the old and new data.

The best solution is give a buffer to vector with the follow command: vector::reserve(size);

Your code could be:

```
std::vector<char> buf;
buf.reserve(10000);
buf.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
buf.shrink_to_fit(); //free the unused memory
```

Comment: if the file has 10 characters this isnt very efficient

Comment: This is basically the same as the already provided answer... By the way, `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()` may perform a reallocation of the whole vector. I'm not sure it worth to risk it here.

Comment: @Fareanor It is similar. About the vector::shrink_to_fit, in the site cppreference.com and cplusplus.com say it just 'reduce the capacity to vector::size'. No way to reallocation when you free memory.

Comment: @idclev you can read the file size instead to use a literal value using the method istream::tellg(). Take a look here: codeyarns.com/2018/02/02/how-to-find-size-of-file-in-c. Then vector::shrink_to_fit will be unnecessary, but if you get a big file it won't be efficient. You need to choose the method that is better for your program.

Comment: Reducing the capacity means reallocation. The documentation is clear about this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit

Comment: How it could reallocate if memory has be freed? I see what is written but it just seem not possible. I made some tests in the past and it didn't happen never. Anyway...

Comment: I found an old discussion about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912507/is-vectorshrink-to-fit-allowed-to-reallocate

Comment: What it seems to me is it has a potential reallocation due to change the already located memory (with realloc), but in practice it never happens.

Comment: Reallocation means changing the size of the allocated memory block, not necessarily moving the memory to a completely new location. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc